# Call a function after a UICollectionView has scrolled a certain distance Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a function that is only called after a `CollectionView` is scrolled or dragged a certain distance and is called repeatedly every time the distance is scrolled.

I also need this function to be called 1 time initially after the `CollectionView` has been loaded.  How could I accomplish this for an `Objective-C` iOS application?

Comment: My first thought is to look at whether the scroll view delegate has been set. If not you can setup one (probably your collection view controller) and assign it. The scroll view delegate has all sorts of methods for tracking dragging. You can use those methods to check the content offset value and decided what if any actions you wish to take.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also contain an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    NSLog(@"%f %f", self.tableView.contentOffset.x, self.tableView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

I think you'll need this.